# How to do Jira JQL pagination

Tags: pagination, jira, jql

I'm getting a list of tickets from Jira through their API. But I can't get the `startAt` and `maxResults` parameters to work.

Php code:

```
$command  = "curl -u abc@xyz.com:$apiToken -X GET -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" https://xyz.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=project+=+%22SC%22&startAt=2&maxResults=40";

$json = exec($command, $return_var);
```

No matter what I do, I always get the default 50 results of the first page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem about Jira REST API, curl just can't get url params. Try cover url with a single quote, it should resolve the case.

```
$command  = "curl -u abc@xyz.com:$apiToken -X GET -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" 'https://xyz.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=project+=+%22SC%22&startAt=2&maxResults=40'";

$json = exec($command, $return_var);
```

Comment: Thanks. The missing quotes were the problem.